# ignoring merges in git

Tags: git, version-control

I've not worked on a project quite some time and have just tried to pull the latest version.

I can't remember the last time I'd worked on the project but I'd obviously had changes made to the Master that I'd not pushed. As I've received some conflict warnings.

Is there  anyway to ignore my previous commits and pull down the master to overwrite my files?

What do you recommend I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm assuming that you've resolved the conflicts now, so that the first commit in `git log` is a merge commit.*

Firstly, it's a good idea save where your old `master` branch was, just in case you want to go back.  You can do that with:

```
git branch old-master master^
```

Then, if you want to reset your `master` branch to the version of `master` that you've just fetched from the `origin` repository, you can do that with `git reset --hard`:

```
# Make sure that you're on the master branch:
git checkout master

# Make sure the remote-tracking branches from origin are up-to-date:
git fetch origin

# Check that there's no output from "git status":
git status

# Now reset master to where origin/master points to:
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that `git reset --hard` is a dangerous command - it will throw away any uncommitted changes, which is why I suggest making sure that the output of `git status` is clean before using it.

Comment: That's great thanks - the 'git branch old-master master^ command is a new one to me. Very useful.

Comment: To add a little to that, the `^` suffix to `master` means to take the first parent of `master`.  (You can also do `master^^` for the grand parent through the first parents, and so on.)  The first parent of a merge commit is always the one that was merged into, i.e. the commit that you were at before the merge.  Thus `master^` will be your master before the merge.  You could also do this with `master@{1}`, which gives you the previous position of the master branch recorded in the reflog - they should be the same in this case, but some might suggest that the latter is more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an easy way would be to backup your local master branch and recreate it... something like:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git branch master -m old-master
git checkout -b master origin/master
git branch -D old-master (if you don't care about your commits there)
```

Hope it helps,